# Resilient Propagation (RProp) training slowly

Tags: c#, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am creating a library for Neural Networks; I have successfully implemented the Back Propagation algorithm, but I'm having trouble with Resilient Propagation.

I have been using the XOR scenario to test my implementation; the error seems to decrease after a few epochs, then it increases and eventually stops changing.

The network I am testing on has 3 layers - 2 input, 2 hidden and 1 output neuron/s. The synapse/dendrite weights are on the following layer's neurons, for example, the input-hidden weights would be stored on the hidden neurons and the hidden-output weights would be stored on the output neurons.

This is my gradient calculation **(EDIT 4)**:

```
private void CalculateGradient()
{
    for (int t = 0; t < TrainingInputs.Count; ++t) //loop through training data
    {
        Network.Run(TrainingInputs[t]);
        for (int l = Network.Layers.Count - 1; l > 0; l--)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Network.Layers[l].Neurons.Count; i++)
            {
                Network.Layers[l].Neurons[i].Delta = l < Network.Layers.Count - 1
                    ? CalculateNonLastGradient(l + 1, i, Network.Layers[l].Neurons[i].Value)
                    : CalculateLastGradient(TrainingOutputs[t][i], Network.Layers[l].Neurons[i].Value);
            }
        }
        for (int l = Network.Layers.Count - 1; l > 0; l--)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Network.Layers[l].Neurons.Count; ++j)
            {
                double grad = Network.Layers[l].Neurons[j].Delta;
                biasGrads[l][j] += grad;

                for (int i = 0; i < Network.Layers[l - 1].Neurons.Count; ++i)
                {
                    grad = Network.Layers[l].Neurons[j].Delta * Network.Layers[l - 1].Neurons[i].Value;
                    grads[l][j][i] += grad;
                }
            }
        }

        int o = 0;
        Layer layer = Network.Layers[Network.Layers.Count - 1];
        errors.Add(layer.Neurons.Sum(n => Math.Abs(TrainingOutputs[t][o++] - n.Value)));
    }
    Error = errors.Average();
}

private double CalculateLastGradient(double ideal, double nValue)
{
    return Network.Activation.Derivitive(nValue) * (ideal - nValue);
}
private double CalculateNonLastGradient(int nextLayer, int j, double nValue)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Network.Layers[nextLayer].Neurons.Count; i++)
    {
        sum += Network.Layers[nextLayer].Neurons[i].Delta * Network.Layers[nextLayer].Neurons[i].Dendrites[j].Weight;
    }
    return Network.Activation.Derivitive(nValue) * sum;
}
```

My RProp implementation **(EDIT 4)**:

```
public bool Algorithm()
{
    //initialise matrices
    if (!initializedMatrices)
    {
        InitializeMatrices();
    }

    ZeroOut();

    //calculate gradients
    CalculateGradient();

    for (int l = 1; l < Network.Layers.Count; l++) //layers
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Network.Layers[l - 1].Neurons.Count; ++i) //prev layer neurons
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Network.Layers[l].Neurons.Count; ++j) //current layer neurons
            {
                double delta = prevDeltas[l][j][i];
                int change = Math.Sign(prevGrads[l][j][i] * grads[l][j][i]);
                if (change > 0)
                {
                    delta = Math.Min(delta * etaPlus, deltaMax);
                    double deltaWeight = -Math.Sign(grads[l][j][i]) * delta;
                    Network.Layers[l].Neurons[j].Dendrites[i].Weight += deltaWeight;
                }
                else if (change < 0)
                {
                    delta = Math.Max(delta * etaMinus, deltaMin);
                    Network.Layers[l].Neurons[j].Dendrites[i].Weight -= prevDeltas[l][j][i];
                    prevGrads[l][j][i] = 0;
                }
                else if (change == 0)
                {
                    double deltaWeight = -Math.Sign(grads[l][j][i]) * delta;
                    Network.Layers[l].Neurons[j].Dendrites[i].Weight += deltaWeight;
                }
                prevGrads[l][j][i] = grads[l][j][i];
                prevDeltas[l][j][i] = delta;
            } //j
        } //i

        for (int i = 1; i < Network.Layers[l].Neurons.Count; ++i)
        {
            double delta = prevBiasDeltas[l][i];
            int change = Math.Sign(prevBiasGrads[l][i] * biasGrads[l][i]);
            if (change > 0)
            {
                delta = Math.Min(prevBiasDeltas[l][i] * etaPlus, deltaMax);
                double biasDeltaWeight = -Math.Sign(biasGrads[l][i]) * delta;
                Network.Layers[l].Neurons[i].Bias += biasDeltaWeight;
            }
            else if (change < 0)
            {
                delta = Math.Max(prevBiasDeltas[l][i] * etaMinus, deltaMin);
                Network.Layers[l].Neurons[i].Bias -= prevBiasDeltas[l][i];
                prevBiasGrads[l][i] = 0;
            }
            else if (change == 0)
            {
                double biasDeltaWeight = -Math.Sign(biasGrads[l][i]) * delta;
                Network.Layers[l].Neurons[i].Bias += biasDeltaWeight;
            }
            prevBiasGrads[l][i] = biasGrads[l][i];
            prevBiasDeltas[l][i] = delta;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

[image: Results of testing the algorithm]

Could anyone point me as to what could be going wrong?

**EDIT:**
The issue seems to be that the delta is not changing.

**EDIT 2:**
I have fixed the delta not changing by initializing the first previous deltas to 0.01 and Zero'ing the gradients before each call. The error increases very fast, then decreases very slowly with TANH; with Sigmoid it does the opposite.

**EDIT 3:**
The loop for the bias' was starting at 0, when it should have been 1. Fixing this fixed the original issue, but has brought up at new one - the error stops decreasing after a certain point.

[image: EDIT 3 Image 1]
[image: EDIT 3 Image 2]

**EDIT 4:** I realised that I had not accumulated the gradients for each neuron over the training set. The error now decreases, but very slowly.